# Delete Twitch Bot's own message using Twurple

Tags: twitch, twitch-api, twurple

I've got a twitch bot that interacts with chat quite a lot using Twurple to parse and send messages.

If the bot replies to somebody, sometimes the response isn't desired/necessary/warranted and we want to remove the chat. The problem is that using Twurple's `onMessage` function doesn't seem to fire when the bot sends a message with `ChatClient.say()`, so I can't store the message ID to delete later.

```
  chatClient.onMessage( async (channel, user, text, data ) => {
      // if conditions met:
      chatClient.say(channel, 'My Message');
  });
```

Now, if "My Message" is something we don't want in chat for some reason, the only way to get it out of chat is for the broadcaster to delete it.

I'd *like* to have an `!undo` command for all moderators to be able to delete the bot's messages.

My thought was that I could just add an array of messages sent *by* the bot, and delete the most recent one, but I can't seem to get the ID from twurple if it's a bot message.

I recall `tmi.js` getting messages from the bot as well, and requiring `if( !self )` for functions to not trigger. I don't really want to maintain a twurple client and a tmi client and just use tmi to delete messages via `!undo` or similar.

Is there a way using `twurple` alone to get the ID of the messages the bot is sending so I can store and act on those?